# get pandoc to be used with R

Tags: r, centos, pandoc

I want to run a **.Rmd** file, I installed the **rmarkdown package**. I execute the .Rmd file with this **command in the terminal**:

```
$: Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd', output_file='file.pdf')"
```

I get this error:

```
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).

Execution halted
```

In R terminal:

```
> rmarkdown::pandoc_available()
[1] FALSE
```

I follow this guide https://pandoc.org/installing.html
And i download pandoc:

```
wget https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.17.0.3/pandoc-1.17.0.3.tar.gz
tar xvzf pandoc-1.17.0.3.tar.gz
```

and now what should I do ? I don't know what I have to put in the environment variables so that r with the package rmarkdown can call pandoc.

Or maybe before, I have to install it but I don't find the `.configure` file so that I can make this command:

```
./configure --prefix="path"
make && make install
```

Comment: You almost certainly don’t want to install Pandoc from source. You should be able to install it via `yum install pandoc pandoc-citeproc`. If this doesn’t work (because … CentOS), the easiest solution is unfortunately to upgrade to a newer system. I wish I was joking.

Comment: Hello, I must install it in a specific directory so that I can load it with a __environment modules system__  (module).

Comment: In that case you can try following the instructions on the installation documentation page for installation from a tarball, and set `$DEST` to a desired location.

Comment: Hello, thank for your help. I get a problem with the installation of **tex live**. I post a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320104/tex-live-installation) if you can help me again.