# Tex Live Installation

Tags: centos, tex-live

I want to generate a pdf file from a Rmd script (r markdown), so I installed Pandoc, in the [installation guide](https://pandoc.org/installing.html), it said: *For PDF output, you’ll need LaTeX. We recommend installing TeX Live*. So I downloaded [Tex Live](https://mirror.bjtu.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/texlive/Source/texlive-20190408-source.tar.xz) from their [website](http://www.tug.org/texlive/).

(I must install it in a specific directory so that I can load it with a environment modules system)

Then i did this:

```
$: tar xf texlive-20190408-source.tar.xz
$: cd texlive-20190408-source
$: sudo ./configure --prefix=$path --enable-build-in-source-tree
$: make 
configure: error: Sorry, you will need at least the Xaw header/library files to compile xdvik.
=== configuring in xdvik failed
make[2]: *** [recurse] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/Downloads/texlive-20190408-source/texk'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/Downloads/texlive-20190408-source/texk'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: You’re really not meant to compile TeX Live from source. As far as I know, this mode of installation is entirely unsupported, it’s only meant for actual development. Download the installer and use that, following the [installation instructions](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) they provide.

Comment: Hello, I can't find myself among the links that lead to other links but I downloaded this **install-tl-unx.tar.gz** (https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/). Is that okay?